# Constant in a derivative "lost" when evaluated at different points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Going through Spivak's Calculus, I have stumbled on the following function

$$\displaystyle{f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}}$$

What I find curious is that when you work towards a derivative at $0$ you get the following

$
\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sqrt{h}}{h} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{h}}, & \text{if } h > 0,\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{-h}}{h} = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-h}}, & \text{if } h < 0.
\end{cases}
$

if the limit is taken for $h \to 0^+$ and $h \to 0^-$, both are undefined, of course.

Now if we work out the derivative at any point $x$ we have:

$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{|x + h|} - \sqrt{|x|}}{h}
$$

we then look at $h > 0$ and $h < 0$ and find: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-x}}$

and this result is consistent with the usual / "mechanical" way people compute derivatives, namely "take one from the power and put it in front", i.e.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \frac{d}{dx} x^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

so my question is: "why don't we see factor of 1/2 in the very first calculation"?

Comment: There is a sharp cusp at $x=0$ and divergent two sided limit, so it appears because of smoother behavior of the function away from the cusp

Comment: "We then look at $h>0$ and $h<0$" does not seem particularly relevant to me. Be as it may, the identity $\frac{\sqrt{\lvert x+h\rvert}-\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}}{h}=\frac{\lvert x+h\rvert-\lvert x\rvert}{h}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{\lvert x+h\rvert}+\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}}$ is just as valid for $x=0$ as it is for $x\ne 0$, but apparently the argument must meet the demands of the situation.

Comment: The result of the first calculation, when you let $h \to 0^+$ to see what the right-hand derivative at the origin is, is $+\infty$, and since “$\frac12 \infty = \infty$” one could argue that you *do* have a factor of 1/2 (or any other factor that you would like!) in the first calculation too...

Comment: indeed, I was thinking about it that way too @HansLundmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain what happens for $x \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{x}$. For $x \leq 0$ in $\sqrt{|x|} = \sqrt{-x}$ there are completely analogous calculations. The point is to analyze what happens to the difference quotients and derivative around and at $x = 0$.

The difference quotient for $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on the interval between $x$ and $x+h$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h}
&= \frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{(x+h) - x}{h\,(\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})} \\
&= \frac{h}{h\,(\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x})}.
\end{align}
$$
This expression is not defined for $h = 0$, but for all other $h$ it's equal to
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}}.
$$
For fixed $x \neq 0$, the limit is the familiar formula for the derivative
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 0} + \sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align}
$$

However, if $x = 0$, then this looks like
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{0+h} + \sqrt{0}},  
$$
which clearly diverges. But you can see the two copies of $\sqrt{x}$ there in the denominator.

I think you might be noticing this factor of $2$ in the derivative formula, which originally comes from the $x$ in the two terms $\sqrt{x+h}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ even though $h$ only appears once.